# How to show that a discrete valuation ring has only two prime ideals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book Algebraic Geometry by Hartshorne, page 74, it is said that the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring $R$ has only two points. How to show that a discrete valuation ring has only two prime ideals? In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring, it is said that a discrete valuation ring has exactly one non-zero maximal ideal.

Comment: A DVR is an integral domain by definition so the zero ideal is prime...

Comment: @fretty, thank you very much. But maybe it has more than two prime ideals.

Comment: Look at point 4 in the list at the top of your linked wiki article: "R is a noetherian local ring with Krull dimension one". With the maximal ideal and the zero ideal, there can thus be no prime ideals between them.

Comment: But a DVR only has one non-zero prime ideal...then with the zero ideal being prime in an integral domain, you have exactly two prime ideals.

Comment: @fretty It might have just one non-zero prime ideal, but the definition only says one non-zero _maximal_ ideal.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you very much. I understand now.

Comment: @LJR While it's not a proof of any kind, I'm glad I could help. As far as I can tell from wikipedia, this can be seen as a consequence of a DVR being a (local) Dedekind domain that is not a field (those always have Krull dimension 1). However, you need to show care so as not to introduce circular arguments here (DVRs and Dedekind domains can be defined from eachother).

Comment: Yes but consequence 6 suggests only one non-zero prime ideal.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you very much.

Comment: @fretty, thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an argument starting from the definition of a DVR as a ring admitting a discrete valuation:

if $P$ is a non-zero prime ideal, then it contains a non-zero element, which can be written in the form $u t^n$, where $u$ is a unit (i.e. has valuation $0$), and $t$ is a uniformizer (i.e. has valuation $1$).  Then $t^n \in P$ (multiply by $u^{-1}$), and then $t \in P$ (using primality).  Thus the unique non-zero ideal of $R$ is the (maximal) ideal of elements of valuation $\geq 1$.

Comment: I think saying a DVR is 'a ring with discrete valuation' is quite misleading, because a DVR is NOT a ring with a valuation having discrete values (take for example $\mathbb{Z}$ with a $p$-adic valuation), but rather the ring of integers of a field with discrete valuation.

Comment: @user: Dear user, Fair enough.  Regards,

Comment: @user10676 : Why hasn't the $p$-adic valuation on $\Bbb Z$ discrete values?

Comment: @Watson: it does have discrete values (meaning that the valuation group is discrete). I am saying that $\mathbb{Z}$ equiped with the $p$-adic valuation is not a DVR (even if the $p$-adic valuation is a [discrete valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation)). It may be confusing because in the standard terminology a [discrete valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation) is only on a field and not ring, and maybe one should not talk about 'rings equipped with a discrete valuation'

Comment: @user10676 : Thank you for your reply! If I understand well, $\Bbb Z$ equiped with the $p$-adic valuation $v_p$ is not a DVR because $$\{x \in \Bbb Q \mid v_p(x) \geq 0\}$$ is larger that $\Bbb Z$ (it contains $p/q$ for any prime $q \neq p$), am I right?